# Zurb Foundation Framework sidebar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have an issue with the zurb foundation framework where the .row class is set to max-width:61.25em; which is 980px wide;

Now the issue I'm having is when I resize the browser down and when it reaches 1024px it pushes the sidebar down. Shouldn't this be happening only at 980px?

You can see what I mean with the browser resizing here http://www.corpalc.com/. I'm trying to give an explanation to my client.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class .large have a min-width 1025px. so when you resize the browser you lose your side bar. But you can put the class medium .

Also a default grid have 12 column.

Comment: Thanks didn't realize that I needed to use the medium class. Thanks for the help.